# Commands not working on Minecraft Realms?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I am an operator (OP) on my friends Realm. Today I tried to play and noticed that no commands would work for me, or anyone else granted OP. They only worked for the owner of said realm.

He has de-oped us and re-oped us with no cure to the problem. What's causing this?

Also another problem that when he tries to reload the realm it fails every single time, any options that would fix this problem?

Comment: Did the owner grant you operator status via clicking the crown icon in Realm settings?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, currently operator permissions don't work at all on any MCPE Realm: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/REALMS-1511

Comment: Hi Fabian, this is now the duplicate target - if any more of these same issues crop up, please VTC as duplicate instead of creating duplicate answers :)

Comment: Just want to add, within the last 18 hours, this has actually been fixed by the Mojang Team. Close the realm, wait 5 minutes then start it back up. This fixes it.

Comment: @Jayden You can edit my answer, best with a link as source.