# Minecraft Realm Operator Glitched

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

The commands for Operators aren't working on realms in Minecraft. We've reset the server, de-opped and re-opped. It doesn't work. If anyone knows any reason or fix for this please let me know. We were developing our new map and now we can't do much to it...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, currently operator permissions don't work at all on any MCPE Realm: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/REALMS-1511

Comment: Similar: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/345457/windows-10-minecraft-op-commands-not-working-on-realms